# MySQL query works in Navicat but generates MySQL Syntax Error elsewhere

Tags: mysql, sql, dreamweaver, syntax-error

Hi everyone and thanks for the help in advance.  I'm frustrated because I'm writing relatively long sql queries (at least for a n00b like me) that work perfectly in NaviCat.  I then import them into the dreamweaver sql editor (where I'm designing my site) and they come back with

```
>   MySQL Error#: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
```

I'll post one of these queries and hopefully somebody can point out to me what I'm doing wrong.

```
 SELECT (SELECT COUNT(GA_Potential.Potential_ID)
FROM GA_Potential
WHERE GA_Potential.Character_ID=14)+  (SELECT COUNT(GA_PurchasedPotential.PurchasedPotential_ID)From GA_PurchasedPotential Where GA_PurchasedPotential.Member_ID=2)+ (SELECT GA_Characters.StartPotential From GA_Characters WHERE GA_Characters.Character_ID =14)+ (SELECT FLOOR(iot_ActingPoints.Acting_Points/10) From iot_ActingPoints WHERE iot_ActingPoints.Member_ID=2)- (SELECT SUM(GA_AttributePoints.Determination_Points) FROM GA_AttributePoints WHERE GA_AttributePoints.Character_ID=14)- (SELECT SUM(GA_AttributePoints.Dexterity_Points) FROM GA_AttributePoints WHERE GA_AttributePoints.Character_ID=14)- (SELECT SUM(GA_AttributePoints.Productivity_Points) FROM GA_AttributePoints WHERE GA_AttributePoints.Character_ID=14)- (SELECT SUM(GA_AttributePoints.Sophistication_Points) FROM GA_AttributePoints WHERE GA_AttributePoints.Character_ID=14)- (SELECT SUM(GA_AttributePoints.Strength_Points) FROM GA_AttributePoints WHERE GA_AttributePoints.Character_ID=14)- (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(GA_CasteAbilitiesForList.Potential_Cost),0) FROM GA_CasteAbilitiesForList,GA_LearnedAblities WHERE GA_CasteAbilitiesForList.Ability_ID=GA_LearnedAblities.Ability_ID AND GA_LearnedAblities.Character_ID=14)- (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(GA_ProfAbilitiesForList.Potential_Cost),0) FROM GA_ProfAbilitiesForList,GA_LearnedAblities WHERE GA_ProfAbilitiesForList.Ability_ID=GA_LearnedAblities.Ability_ID AND GA_LearnedAblities.Character_ID=14) AS TOTAL
```

This generates exactly the number I want in NaviCat.

Edit:  I stripped out all of the single quotes that NaviCat puts in automatically, and I still get the same error.

Thanks in advance.

-CB

Comment: The error message is cut off exactly at the point where it gets interesting!

Comment: Sorry Tom!  I don't know why I didn't think it was relevant.  Here's the full message:  MySQL Error#: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Comment: @user1262890 - Instead of trying to troubleshoot the whole thing. What happens if you try it with just the first select? ie `SELECT (
 SELECT COUNT(GA_Potential.Potential_ID)
 FROM   GA_Potential
 WHERE   GA_Potential.Character_ID=14
 ) AS TOTAL` If that works, add in the second one. Any change? You might also investigate whether you could rewrite as one two or three smaller queries using `CASE` It would be more readable and probably better performance as well.

Comment: Good suggestion; I've been trying every conceivable iteration of this query using just the first few parts.  `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(GA_Potential.Potential_ID) FROM GA_Potential WHERE GA_Potential.Character_ID=14+) AS TOTAL` returns `MySQL Error#: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2`. Of course the query works if you remove the initial SELECT(), but then the query comes back with the wrong numbers when you try to sum them.

Comment: I also don't see how I'd do this using `CASE`.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: @user1262890 - May be nothing, but you have a trailing "+" in the wrong place above. Fyi, use a "@" in front of someone's name and they will be notified when you leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hip shot: maybe you need to use parentheses around all of the subselects, like

```
SELECT 
((SELECT COUNT(`GA_Potential`.`Potential_ID`) From`GA_Potential` WHERE`GA_Potential`.`Character_ID`=14)+ 
(SELECT COUNT(`GA_PurchasedPotential`.`PurchasedPotential_ID`)From`GA_PurchasedPotential` Where`GA_PurchasedPotential`.`Member_ID`=2)+
(SELECT `GA_Characters`.`StartPotential` From `GA_Characters` WHERE `GA_Characters`.`Character_ID` =14)+
(SELECT FLOOR(`iot_ActingPoints`.`Acting_Points`/10) From `iot_ActingPoints` WHERE `iot_ActingPoints`.`Member_ID`=2)-
(SELECT SUM(`GA_AttributePoints`.`Determination_Points`) FROM `GA_AttributePoints` WHERE `GA_AttributePoints`.`Character_ID`=14)-
(SELECT SUM(`GA_AttributePoints`.`Dexterity_Points`) FROM `GA_AttributePoints` WHERE `GA_AttributePoints`.`Character_ID`=14)-
(SELECT SUM(`GA_AttributePoints`.`Productivity_Points`) FROM `GA_AttributePoints` WHERE `GA_AttributePoints`.`Character_ID`=14)-
(SELECT SUM(`GA_AttributePoints`.`Sophistication_Points`) FROM `GA_AttributePoints` WHERE `GA_AttributePoints`.`Character_ID`=14)-
(SELECT SUM(`GA_AttributePoints`.`Strength_Points`) FROM `GA_AttributePoints` WHERE `GA_AttributePoints`.`Character_ID`=14)-
(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`GA_CasteAbilitiesForList`.`Potential_Cost`),0) FROM `GA_CasteAbilitiesForList`,`GA_LearnedAblities` WHERE `GA_CasteAbilitiesForList`.`Ability_ID`=`GA_LearnedAblities`.`Ability_ID` AND `GA_LearnedAblities`.`Character_ID`=14)-
(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(`GA_ProfAbilitiesForList`.`Potential_Cost`),0) FROM `GA_ProfAbilitiesForList`,`GA_LearnedAblities` WHERE `GA_ProfAbilitiesForList`.`Ability_ID`=`GA_LearnedAblities`.`Ability_ID` AND `GA_LearnedAblities`.`Character_ID`=14))
AS total
```

also: does the error message really end at the `near`?

Comment: With the extra parentheses the query still works in Navicat and when I "test" it in Dreamweaver, but it generates an error when I try to use the data.  I amended my earlier post to include the  rest of the error.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem - leaving this here for other who run into this:

Dreamweaver doesn't like multiple SELECT statements in the SQL.  I was able to re-work my query to not need multiple SELECT statements and the error went away.

As an additional note, I thought it was the parentheticals, but they seem to work fine with other functions.